# Problem with side by side figures and captions

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, floats

I want to have 4 figures side by side and centered in my paper. I am using this code. The problem is that captions and figures are not aligned. It seems captions are in correct position, but figures are not and directed to right side. Captions are not below of the figures. I am using a double-column format.

```
\begin{figure*}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\begin{minipage}{115pt}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=180pt]{1.pdf}
\vspace{-75pt}
\caption{aaaa}
\end{minipage}
&
\begin{minipage}{115pt}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=180pt]{2.pdf}
\vspace{-75pt}
\caption{bbbb}
\end{minipage}
&
\begin{minipage}{115pt}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=180pt]{3.pdf}
\vspace{-75pt}
\caption{cccc}
\end{minipage}
&
\begin{minipage}{120pt}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=180pt]{4.pdf}
\vspace{-75pt}
\caption{dddd}
\end{minipage}
\end{tabular}
\end{figure*}
```

Comment: The need for a negative `\vspace` suggests that your images have white borders around them.

Comment: if you put a 180pt wide figure into a 115pt minipage the `\centering` will have no effect and the figure will be an overfull box sticking out on the right.

Comment: Why not trying the `subcaption` package that would handle spacing for you ?

Comment: There's a lot of repetition in your code. You should consider defining a single macro to automate the task of inserting the minipages.

Answer (score 2):

Doing figures next to each other is easier with the subfig environment. Like `Uneo` suggests, load the `subcaption` package. The code you are looking for is probably something like this:

```
\begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.25\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width=180pt]{1.pdf}
                \caption{aaa}
                \label{fig:a}
        \end{subfigure}
        %add/remove whitelines for spacing between pictures

        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.25\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width=180pt]{2.pdf}
                \caption{bbbb}
                \label{fig:b}
        \end{subfigure}

        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.25\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width=180pt]{3.pdf}
                \caption{ccc}
                \label{fig:c}
        \end{subfigure}

        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.25\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width=180pt]{4.pdf}
                \caption{ddd}
                \label{fig:d}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{zzzzz}\label{fig:z}
\end{figure}
```

This is an adaptation from the example in the wikibook [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Subfloats). You will have to play around with the width of the images and the figures to get everything in the right position, but without the actual images thats not possible for me.

The example uses the packages `graphicx`, `caption` and `subcaption`.